# How to Perform Inner Join in Grid DB using TQL

Tags: griddb

As a data analyst, I frequently work with many kinds of data, each stored in its own GridDB container. I wanted to perform an Inner Join using GridDB's TQL syntax, which as follows:

```sql
SELECT customers.customer_id, orders.order_id, orders.order_date
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id;
```

As you can see in the above example, I need to generate the table by performing an inner join between the customers and orders tables to determine a customer's order details. I tried this query on GridDB containers but recieved the following error:

```bash
Syntax error: unexpected token "INNER"
```

However, the command is already supported by GridDB as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/sqlreference/sql-commands-supported/#join) as well. Or am I doing something wrong here?

P.S. The snapshot from the documentation is also shown below:
[image: Inner Join Documentation]